# angular 7 input number validation

Tags: angular

In angularjs:

```
<form name="f" novalidate>
<input type="number" ng-model="x" name="x">
</form>

<div ng-if="f.x.$error.number">NaN</div>
```

Can I get same in Angular?

E.g. `<input type="number">` is valid in Angular7 is input is 'eee'.

`<input type="number" required>` is invalid if input is 'eee', but also invalid for ''.

**Edit**

As far as I see if I try to add some validator - it receives empty value in case of 'non-numeric' value.

**Edit 2**

Prolly will use workaround like this:

```
nativeNumber(element: ElementRef):ValidatorFn {
        return () => {
            return element.nativeElement.validity.valid ? null : {'number': true};
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by adding Validators of Angular,

There is an existing one for Required: [Angular Form Validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)

You can use pattern and pass a Regex to check for numeric: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/

Then add reference to your input by declaring it as FormControl, add the validators and pass the reference in the input's formControl Attribute. Dont forget to add your newly created form control on your form group.

add to Class:

```
let numericRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
let myNumeric = new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.pattern(numericRegex), // <-- Here's how you pass in the custom validator using regex.
]);
```

Template:

```
<input class="form-control"
      [formControl]="myNumeric" required >

  <div *ngIf="myNumeric.errors.required">
    value is required.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="myNumeric.errors.pattern">
    only alphanumeric
  </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I dont need required in some places - I want to allow blanks, but not non-numbers and I want to keep input type number, so pattern wont work. And btw your pattern is wrong...

Comment: So, you want numbers and blanks only? Any specifics why or where would you use this validation? Is it for a phone number or something?

Comment: I want maximum versatility here -- e.g. in some places empty value is allowed, in some not.

Answer (score 1):

I like to validate my forms with FormGroup and FormBuilder.

Angular 7 HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
  <input type="number" ng-model="x" name="x" 
   formControlName="myInputField">
</form>
```

Typescript:

```
public myFormGroup: FormGroup;
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, ...) {
  this.myFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    myInputField: ['', [Validators.required, 
    Validators.pattern('^\\d*$')]]
  });
}
```

So it validates immediately. I hope I could help.

Comment: I dont need required in some places - I want to allow blanks, but not non-numbers and I want to keep input type number, so pattern wont work. And btw your pattern is wrong too...

Comment: If you want to allow blank you just can remove the `Validators.required` since all Validators are  in an array.
Why do you want to keep input type number so urgently?
Where did you find an error in my pattern? Let me know. I hope we can get your wished result.

Comment: .1 1.1. 1e1 are all valid numbers